# Monitor Kill by task manager callback

Tags: android

How can I find out the moment, when my android application will be killed by task manager. 
If there any callback in Activity class or something else?

Comment: There is no way without some hacks into Android.  What are you trying to do?  A well written mobile app can be killed at any time and will still behave properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

[image]

`onDestroy()` should get called (But it's not guaranteed to be called).

Comment: Note that `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: I've written test application and found out that onDestroy() does not call.

Answer (score 0):

Task Killer is used by Android when overall system is running low on memory. And then, it will start freeing the system memory by killing apps.

So,app can possibly gets hint if in Activity, it implements onLowMemory().
As per Android documentation,

This is called when the overall system is running low on memory, and would like actively running process to try to tighten their belt. While the exact point at which this will be called is not defined, generally it will happen around the time all background process have been killed, that is before reaching the point of killing processes hosting service and foreground UI that we would like to avoid killing.

Comment: Probably you have meant OOM killer. But I need signal when user close application from task manager.

Comment: yes, I was assuming the OOM Killer. Since Android task can be composed of activities from different applications, not sure if Activity has any call back to register user-triggered app closure. Activity life-cycle events such as onPause(), onStop() can be then the places where you can implement the code which will be invoked in case of user-triggered app closure